# Identifying default outlook profile

Tags: outlook

I have managed to return all the profiles using this registry path:-
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000002

However I am now wondering how to determine the default profile. In other words is there a reg key that identifies the default profile from the rest of the profiles.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you define "default" profile?  There is no "default" profile.  Sometimes when you don't give it a name, Outlook will just name it "Default", but that's really about it.  It doesn't have any magical properties.

Comment: @roryap in Outlook you can define a default profile - which gets focused first in your profilelist at startup

Comment: @roryap - Control Panel | Mail | Show Profiles | Always use this profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Outlook 97-2010**
The `REG_SZ` `DefaultProfile` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles` 
contains the value (subkeyname) of the default profile.

**Since Outlook 2013 (v15)**
The same structure exists for newer versions in
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\%version%\Outlook\Profiles`

[image]

Comment: On my system, it's stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles`.  I don't have the key you mentioned.

Comment: @roryap It depends on your outlook version. 
Starting with Outlook 2013 (15). Prior to that the profiles are in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles - but your right i should have this in my answer

Comment: For me in Outlook 2016, the `DefaultProfile` key is stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook`, not down in `Outlook\Profiles`.

Answer (score 2):

The officially supported way (Extended MAPI in C++ or Delphi, works in all versions of Outlook) is to use the `IMAPITable` object returned from `IProfAdmin::GetProfileTable` and look for a row with the `PR_DEFAULT_PROFILE` property == true. You can see it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click IProfAdmin button).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (any language, I am also its author) is an option, you can do the following:

```
Set rSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
MsgBox rSession.Profiles.DefaultProfileName
```

Comment: Yes, i would also prefere an officially supporte way, but the question targets: "..is there a reg key that identifies the default profile from the rest of the profiles"